# How to print out multiple rows of XML values using SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a database called Companies.
There is a table within Companies called Employees.
Within Employees there is a column that contains an XML response. The Column is called Data.

The XML Response looks like this

```
<Employee>
  <Tenure>7</Tenure>
  <Age>55</Age>
  <OfficesVisited>
    <int>1132</int>
    <int>3345</int>
    <int>7534</int>
</OfficesVisited>
</Employee>
```

What I would like my sql query to print out is:

OfficesVisited

1132

3345

7534

What I am currently getting is 113233457534

I am using this sql query:

```
use Companies
SELECT Employees.Data.query('(/Employee/OfficesVisited/int/text())') as OfficesVisited
    FROM Employees
    Where Employee.Employee_ID = 65035277
```

I've tried using OUTER APPLY and CROSS APPLY and I can get it into 3 rows but all three rows look like the above.

Can Anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. It shows how to use `.nodes()` and `.value()` XML methods correctly.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [data] XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl ([data]) VALUES
(N'<Employee>
    <Tenure>7</Tenure>
    <Age>55</Age>
    <OfficesVisited>
        <int>1132</int>
        <int>3345</int>
        <int>7534</int>
    </OfficesVisited>
</Employee>')
, (N'<Employee>
    <Tenure>77</Tenure>
    <Age>58</Age>
    <OfficesVisited>
        <int>7777</int>
        <int>8888</int>
    </OfficesVisited>
</Employee>')
, (N'<Employee>
    <Tenure>90</Tenure>
    <Age>50</Age>
    <OfficesVisited>
        <int>1111</int>
    </OfficesVisited>
</Employee>');
-- DDL and samplex data population, end

SELECT c.value('(./text())[1]','INT') AS    OfficesVisited 
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.[data].nodes('/Employee/OfficesVisited/int') AS t(c)
WHERE id IN (1,2);
```

> Output

```
+----------------+
| OfficesVisited |
+----------------+
|           1132 |
|           3345 |
|           7534 |
|           7777 |
|           8888 |
+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped with this specific query but in the long term I'll have to look up multiple Employee IDs at once, so would that mean pasting in each xml table every time?

Comment: If your DB table has multiple rows with XML, the same SQL statement will produce a rectangular result for all rows.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. In My example I used an Employee ID in the Where clause. If I have 3 employee IDs what would this query look like?

Comment: So I have hundreds of employee IDs to iterate through, will I have to go get each XML response for this to work?

Comment: I don't understand your latest question. I think that I answered your original question in the post.